# How to disable mnemonic for JavaFX MenuBar?

Tags: javafx, menubar, keyevent, mnemonics, alt-key

In my stage I have inserted a menubar at the top like usual for programs. I want to give the ALT key (together with arrow keys) some logic in another context within the stage. But everytime I press ALT and arrows I unintentionally navigate through the menus of the menubar, too.

I want to avoid that or better completely disable this mnemonic behavior.
Setting the mnemonicParsing properties of all menus to false failed. I also tried this approach without success:

```
menubar.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> e.consume());
```

Answer (score 6):

When <kbd>ALT</kbd> is pressed first menu gets focus and when menus have focus, arrow keys cause navigation among them whether <kbd>ALT</kbd> is pressed or not. So in order to prevent this behavior you need to prevent first menu getting focus when <kbd>ALT</kbd> is pressed.

Looking at the `MenuBarSkin` class' constructor source code, gives us the solution:

> ```
> public MenuBarSkin(final MenuBar control) {
>     ...
>     Utils.executeOnceWhenPropertyIsNonNull(control.sceneProperty(), (Scene scene) -> {
>         scene.getAccelerators().put(acceleratorKeyCombo, firstMenuRunnable);
>
>         // put focus on the first menu when the alt key is pressed
>         scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
>             if (e.isAltDown()  && !e.isConsumed()) {
>                 firstMenuRunnable.run();
>             }
>         });
>     });
>     ...
> }
> ```

---

### Solution:

As you had already guessed, solution is to consume the event when <kbd>ALT</kbd> is down but you need to add the EventHandler to the `scene` not `menubar`:

```
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        // your desired behavior
        if(event.isAltDown())
            event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic answer all around, you even looked up the original source where the key listener is registered. Thank you, you well deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can rewrite MenuBar skin.
Javafx has made the choice (*or is it a bug* ?) that focus is given to MenuBar when ALT key is **pressed**, not **released**, which is the standard behavior in Eclipse, Netbeans, ....
Furthemore, focus should not be given to MenuBar when ALT_GRAPH key is pressed or released.

Here is the patch I propose.
Note that only the first diffs are relevant, the last diff is just for the code to compile when one have not access to the code.
Basically I have split the "firstMenuRunnable" in 3 functions

- firstMenuRunnable is used only when F10 key is pressed
- deselectOnKeyPressed is used when menuBar has focus and ALT key is
  pressed
- focusOnFirstMenuOnKeyReleased is used when menuBar has not
  focus and ALT key is released

Hence, one can have the **standard behavior, allowing accelerators using ALT key without focus being taken by MenuBar**.

```
    --- com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/MenuBarSkin.java in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\javafx-src.zip
    +++ C:\Users\daniel\dev\xxx\Layout\src\com\stimulus\control\MenuBarSkin.java     
@@ -372,12 +491,21 @@
             scene.getAccelerators().put(acceleratorKeyCombo, firstMenuRunnable);

             // put focus on the first menu when the alt key is pressed
+            scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
+                altDown = false;
+            });
             scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
-                if (e.isAltDown()  && !e.isConsumed()) {
-                    firstMenuRunnable.run();
+                if (e.isAltDown() && !e.isConsumed() && e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ALT)) {
+                    deselectMenusOnKeyPressed.run();
+                    altDown = true;
                 }
             });
+            scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
+                if (altDown) {
+                    focusOnFirstMenuOnKeyReleased.run();
+                }
         });
+        });

         ParentTraversalEngine engine = new ParentTraversalEngine(getSkinnable());
         engine.addTraverseListener(this);
    @@ -434,7 +453,50 @@
                 }
             };

    +    private boolean menuDeselectedOnKeyPressed = false;

    +    Runnable deselectMenusOnKeyPressed = new Runnable() {
    +        public void run() {
    +            /*
    +             ** check that this menubar's container has contents,
    +             ** and that the first item is a MenuButton....
    +             ** otherwise the transfer is off!
    +             */
    +            menuDeselectedOnKeyPressed = false;
    +            if (container.getChildren().size() > 0) {
    +                if (container.getChildren().get(0) instanceof MenuButton) {
    +//                        container.getChildren().get(0).requestFocus();
    +                    if (focusedMenuIndex >= 0) {
    +                        unSelectMenus();
    +                        menuDeselectedOnKeyPressed = true;
    +                    }
    +                }
    +            }
    +        }
    +    };
    +    Runnable focusOnFirstMenuOnKeyReleased = new Runnable() {
    +        public void run() {
    +            /*
    +             ** check that this menubar's container has contents,
    +             ** and that the first item is a MenuButton....
    +             ** otherwise the transfer is off!
    +             */
    +            if (container.getChildren().size() > 0) {
    +                if (container.getChildren().get(0) instanceof MenuButton) {
    +//                        container.getChildren().get(0).requestFocus();
    +                    if (focusedMenuIndex == -1 && !menuDeselectedOnKeyPressed) {
    +                        unSelectMenus();
    +                        menuModeStart(0);
    +                        openMenuButton = ((MenuBarButton) container.getChildren().get(0));
    +                        openMenu = getSkinnable().getMenus().get(0);
    +                        openMenuButton.setHover();
    +                    }
    +                }
    +            }
    +        }
    +    };
    +
         private boolean pendingDismiss = false;

         // For testing purpose only.
    @@ -650,9 +712,23 @@
                 menuButton.textProperty().bind(menu.textProperty());
                 menuButton.graphicProperty().bind(menu.graphicProperty());
                 menuButton.styleProperty().bind(menu.styleProperty());
    +            // patch because MenuButtonSkin.AUTOHIDE is private
    +            final String AUTOHIDE;
    +            {
    +                try {
    +                    Class<?> clazz = MenuButtonSkin.class;
    +//                    System.out.println("fields = " + Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()).toString());
    +                    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("AUTOHIDE");
    +                    field.setAccessible(true);
    +                    AUTOHIDE = (String) field.get(this);
    +                    field.setAccessible(false);
    +                } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    +                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex);
    +                }
    +            }
                 menuButton.getProperties().addListener((MapChangeListener<Object, Object>) c -> {
    -                 if (c.wasAdded() && MenuButtonSkin.AUTOHIDE.equals(c.getKey())) {
    -                    menuButton.getProperties().remove(MenuButtonSkin.AUTOHIDE);
    +                if (c.wasAdded() && AUTOHIDE.equals(c.getKey())) {
    +                    menuButton.getProperties().remove(AUTOHIDE);
                         menu.hide();
                     }
                 });
```

Below is the complete code of my MenuBar:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.stimulus.control;

import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

/**
 *
 * @author daniel
 */
public class CustomMenuBar extends MenuBar {

    public CustomMenuBar() {
    }

    public CustomMenuBar(Menu... menus) {
        super(menus);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MenuBarSkin(this) {

        };
    }

}
```