# Release mnemonic when application loses focus

Tags: javafx, menu, window

## Background

Due to a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090647), JavaFX applications that use a [MenuBar](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html) will keep the mnemonic selected ("latched") when the user presses <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to switch to another program. When the user returns to the JavaFX application, the framework retains the latch.

## Problem

If the user then presses a letter that corresponds to the mnemonic, then the letter is consumed and that menu is opened.

This behaviour is not what users have come to expect from an application: it interrupts workflow. Rather, <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> should not put the application in a state whereby the menu can open. This is conflating <kbd>Alt</kbd> by itself to trigger the menu with <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, a conceptually different operation.

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36009964/59087) seek to disable the mnemonic, but we want to clear the latch so that when the user returns to the application, pressing a letter will not trigger opening the menu.

## Question

How do you instruct a JavaFX application to clear the latched mnemonics when <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> is pressed (i.e., the application focus is lost)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of parts to this solution: releasing the mnemonics and consuming the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key press. Be sure to implement both.

### Release mnemonics

One way to work around the bug is to add a focus listener to the application's [Stage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html) that fires a key released event for all known mnemonics. Given a `Stage` instance, we can iterate over all the main menu mnemonics as follows:

```java
stage.focusedProperty().addListener( ( c, lost, show ) -> {
  if( lost ) {
    for( final var mnemonics : stage.getScene().getMnemonics().values() ) {
      for( final var mnemonic : mnemonics ) {
        mnemonic.getNode().fireEvent( keyUp( ALT, false ) );
      }
    }
  }
  else if( show ) {
    // Make sure the menu does not capture focus.
    stage.getScene().focusOwnerProperty().get().requestFocus();
  }
} );
```

We'll need a few helper methods to create the key release event:

```java
public static Event keyDown( final KeyCode code, final boolean shift ) {
  return keyEvent( KEY_PRESSED, code, shift );
}

public static Event keyUp( final KeyCode code, final boolean shift ) {
  return keyEvent( KEY_RELEASED, code, shift );
}

private static Event keyEvent(
  final EventType<KeyEvent> type, final KeyCode code, final boolean shift ) {
  return new KeyEvent(
    type, "", "", code, shift, false, false, false
  );
}
```

With those methods in place, cycling windows by pressing <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> no longer opens the menu upon returning to the JavaFX application followed by pressing a mnemonic key (such as "f" for the "File" menu).

### Consume event

Additionally, make the scene consume the event:

```java
scene.addEventHandler( KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
  final var code = event.getCode();

  if( event.isAltDown() && (code == ALT_GRAPH || code == ALT) ) {
    event.consume();
  }
} );
```